Stack trace doesn’t point to the origin of API call when throwing an exception with Retrofit
I am using Retrofit, OkHttp, Kotlin coroutines to make HTTP requests.
When the server returns an unsuccessful result (e.g., 404), I throw a custom exception, which is a subtype of IOException.
The resulted stack trace does not point to code that initially made a request.
The resulted stack trace only points to interceptor code, which doesn’t help me identify the original call site.
Question:
How can I ensure that when I throw a custom exception (a subtype of IOException), the stack trace points to code that initially made a request (e.g. catApi.callThatReturns404())?
Constraints:

Wrapping every remote API call with try/catch is not an option because the issue is global, and I don’t want to wrap it in hundreds of places.
Simply logging inside the interceptor is not sufficient since I need the full stack trace.
Avoiding the use of the custom exception is not an option, as it holds information.
Solution should also work in production code. Not only when some debug tools are turned on

Example code
fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {
    makeApiCall()
}

private suspend fun makeApiCall() {
    val api = createCatApi()
    api.callThatReturns404()
}

private fun createCatApi(): CatApi {
    val url = "https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/"
    val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor { chain ->
            val response = chain.proceed(chain.request())
            if (!response.isSuccessful) {
                throw SubTypeOfIOException(response)
            }
            response
        }
        .build()
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(url)
        .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule()))
        .client(httpClient)
        .build()
    return retrofit.create<CatApi>()
}

interface CatApi {
    @GET("factss")
    suspend fun callThatReturns404(): Collection<Any>
}

Stack trace, when SubTypeOfIOException is thrown
Exception in thread "main" com.SubTypeOfIOException: 404
    at com.MainKt$createCatApi$$inlined$-addInterceptor$1.intercept(OkHttpClient.kt:1082)

What I want
Exception in thread "main" com.retrofit_test.SubTypeOfIOException: 404
    at com.retrofit_test.Main.makeApiCall(Main.kt:20)
    at com.MainKt$main$1.invokeSuspend(Main.kt:15)
    at com.MainKt.main(Main.kt:14)
Caused by: com.SubTypeOfIOException: 404
    at com.MainKt$createCatApi$$inlined$-addInterceptor$1.intercept(OkHttpClient.kt:1082)

Interesting thing: when I call such code from tests and throw IOException, the stack trace contains information I want. If in tests I throw a subtype of IOException, the stack trace does not contain such information
Versions:

org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.9.0
com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.11.0
com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.12.0


if the lack of frames is related to the coroutines, https://github.com/Anamorphosee/stacktrace-decoroutinator might help.

Thank you for your suggestion! After installing stacktrace-decoroutinator,some previously missing frames are visible. However, several issues remain:

Some stack frames are still absent.
I’m hesitant to use stacktrace-decoroutinator in production, as it handles low-level functionality that I believe should be addressed by the standard Kotlin libraries.
The library introduces several warnings.
Because of these reasons, I'm looking for a more robust, built-in solution for production use.


Thank you for the feedback. If you believe that Decoroutinator has to be the part of the standard library you may vote for the issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-50720/Kotlinx.coroutines-debugging-Support-Stacktrace-decoroutinator-like-solution. And it will be great if you’d share an example of an absence of frames in the Decoroutinator issues section
